# pandas Grouper by month aggregation returns previous month as datetime index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using the following code to group by ohlc (open, high, low, close) prices into a monthly aggregate.

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M',level=0,label='left')).agg(ohlc_dict)
```

This code is working perfectly to aggregate for minutes, days and weeks. But when I aggregate for months it is returning me as the datetime value of the last day of the previous month (instead of the first day of the actual month). For example:

```
datetime                                                                 
2004-05-31 20:59:00
```

is being aggregated to:

```
datetime                                                                 
2004-04-30
```

If I use `label='right'` it will return me `2005-05-31`, the desired value for this statement is `2005-05-01`. Why this is happening and what is the best way to achieve the desired statement?

Thank you

Comment: use `freq='MS'`

Comment: @MaxU perfect, thank you very much

Comment: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @MaxU offered, use `freq='MS'` instead of `'M'`. 
You can see all the possible frequencies here:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases